# Issue with asp.net webapi and business logic

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Am writing a service using asp.netwebapi visual studio 13 i am not getting how to integrate or communicate models with business layer. because if i use 3 tier architecture context will act as models no difference in that so please any body suggest me the communication between the models and business layer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create `Models` in your WebAPI to separate your BLL from WebAPI. For example, if you have a `Person` class in your BLL you can have a `PersonModel` in your WebAPI. It would work like below roughly.

```
[HttpGet]
Public HttpResponseMessage Get(id)
{
    // Validation for id
    var person = _dbContext.GetPersonById(id);

    // Now populate the Model
    var personModel=new PersonModel();

     // You can use automapper to replace the following part
    personModel.PersonId=person.PersonId;
    personModel.Firstname= person.Firstname; 
    // ....
}


[HttpPost]
Public HttpResponseMessage Post(PersonModel personModel)
{
    // Validation here
    // ...

    var person = new Person();

    // You can use automapper to replace the following part
    person.PersonId= personModel.PersonId;
    person.Firstname=personModel.Firstname;

    _dbContext.Save(person);
}
```

You can use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) to automatically populate the models without having to write Model <-> BLL class code.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion i will get back to u again about this issue